# Android catching touch event in separate class

Tags: android

I need to be able to recognize touch event in the app.
Obviously this can be done by overriding dispatchTouchEvent in main activity.
However I can not do this since the catching logic should be done in separate jar library. 
The app can past context if needed.
Smth like this:
MainActivity calls Init of MyClass (which is in jar) and passing App Context, then MyClass register OntouchListener (or smth else) to catch any touch event in MainActivity.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Actually after thinking about it more - I have found that if override then it should be not dispatchTouchEvent() but onUserInteraction() because what I really need is just to detect that the app is not active (there is no any user interaction) during some time ... Still would like to find the way to do this beside of triviral overriding of onUserInteraction() in base activity and then extending all app activities from them. Any possibility to queary the app when the last user interaction happens (without modifying the app activities code) ?

Answer (score 0):

Override the `dispatchTouchEvent`, and relay it to your `MyClass`.

In your original class:

```
@Override
public void dispatchTouchEvent(...){
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(...);
    myClass.dispatchTouchEvent(...);
}
```

Instead of directly accessing the `MyClass` instance, you could create a method `setDispatchTouchEventListener(DispatchTouchEventListener listener)` in your original class, where `DispatchTouchEventListener` is an interface with the `dispatchTouchEvent(...)` method.

Comment: Let me clarify - the requirement is the only change allowed in MainActivity is to instantiate or call Init of MyClass, again the context or any other activity parameters can be passed their.

Comment: If you really, really want this, have a look at AspectJ. But this is not an easy thing to step into.

Comment: Nobody is going to create DispatchTouchEventListener in MainActivity. The only what I can request to add to MainActivity is call MyClass.init(...)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't override dispatchTouchEvent in the activity you want to catch touch event, there is no way of listening for touch events from other activities even if you initialize the activity you want to listen for touch events

Comment: Its easy to say No, but I feel it should be a way. Nothing can be done through context or MainActivity instance passed to MyClass?

Answer (score 0):

You have a very weird requirement in that you can only pass things into MyClass#Init(..). In reality, to do this, you need to have the method inside MyClass already and call it from an overwritten MainActivity.disatchTouchEvent(...).

Comment: I guess the discussion is this weird or not is out of the scope. Let me clarify last time though - MainActivity is not in my hands - I can not request them what to do.

Comment: That's fine. You don't need access to MainActivity. I'm saying MyClass (which you do have access too), should have a method like takeTouchEvent(...). The person who's creating MainActivity would then pass your class the touch event, however they see fit, or remove the idea of a touch event totally and have them do calls instead (like onLongTouch() or onShortTouch()...watever). You cannot do anything from a Context...

Comment: Suppose "The person who's creating MainActivity" dont' want to deal with touch events - this is just not his/her business. Can I do anything inside MyClass to catch the touch events (using any MainActivity parameters then can pass in OnCreate) ?

Comment: It's solely the business of the Activity creator to handle user interaction and not an underlying library. An underlying library can provide solutions to user interactions that the Activity creator uses, but it cannot "hijack" the user experience. So, long story short, your activity creator must be the direct provider of such actions.

Comment: By not his business I mean they dont want to bother with this. Btw its another problem to ask this from app. App can has other activities, so to ask them overide dispatchtouch in all app activities? Sounds to much.

Comment: It sounds like you need to provide the framework for all Activities in their program then. You can do this by making MyClass in your library extend Activity and have the developer extend MyClass instead of Activity. That way you provide the Activity framework for them and can manage the touch events yourself.

Comment: Yes I know this is the one solution. There are 2 problems with it though: 1. I don't think I can force them not extend from Activity but extend only from MyClass. 2. There is no garanty they are not going to override dispatchTouchEvent() or onUserInteraction() again in their class. As I said before I just need indication the app is active - means user interactions happens. The best thing is smth like BroadcastReceiver - but unfortantly looks like there is no such intent - "touch event", at least it's not mentioned in official documentation. Will try GestureListener.

Comment: It's the same when you override onCreate() from Activity. You have to call super.onCreate(). If they decide to override, dispatchTouchEvent() they should likewise call super.dispatchTouchEvent(). It's not your problem if they are bad programmers. Anyway, I dont know what to tell ya. You can't steal touch events from an Activity. No matter what, they will have to pass it to you somehow.

Comment: Agree - calling of super is an argument. I am very appreciate your responses. I don't need ( and dont want to steal) - I just need to be triggered when touch event happens - that it. And it is very desirable this notification should come not from the Activity but from Android FWK. Probably from InputDispatcher. After looking 2days I agree - there is no standard way. I still didn't lost the hope - there should be a "hack" way.